# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined for table row

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, html-table

I want to alternate colors for my html table.

To achieve this I have wrote following function:

```
function drawColorfullShelves(){
     var table = document.getElementById("table");
     for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
         if( i%2 == 0){
            row[i].style.color = "rgb(200, 226, 252)";
         }else{
             row[i].style.color = "rgb(251, 251, 251)";

         }
     }

 }
```

But in browser console I  see following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

How to fix it?

Comment: If `row = table.rows[i]`, then what is `row[i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the following.  You have a table with x number of rows your loop defines that each variable row is table.rows[i].  This means that in each iteration you have your hands on the row.  Then in your if statement you try to access row[i].  This is just not valid.  Below is the corrected code.

```
function drawColorfullShelves() {
     var table = document.getElementById("table");
     for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
         if( i%2 == 0) {
            row.style.color = "rgb(200, 226, 252)";
         } else {
            row.style.color = "rgb(251, 251, 251)";
         }
     }
 }
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2pk7uvoy/

I also must note that arrays in javascript are zero based. Your for loop starts at 1 and not zero.  Was this intended?  Do you want to skip the first row? if not then below should be your corrected code.

```
function drawColorfullShelves() {
     var table = document.getElementById("table");
     for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
         if( i%2 == 0) {
            row.style.color = "rgb(200, 226, 252)";
         } else {
            row.style.color = "rgb(251, 251, 251)";
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using javascript for this? It is super simple to do using CSS.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
   color: rgb(251, 251, 251);
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
   color: rgb(200, 226, 252);
}
```

Comment: because in javascipt I sometimes hide some rows